# Update JSON variable based on Mongoose results

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I have a JSON variable outside of mongoDB collection as below

> ```
>         var outputJson = [
>             {
>                 'Product' : 'TV',
>                 'isSelected': 0
>             },
>             {
>                 'Product' : 'Radio',
>                 'isSelected': 0
>             },
>             {
>                 'Product' : 'Book',
>                 'isSelected': 0
>             },                      
>             {
>                 'Product' : 'Watch',
>                 'isSelected': 0
>             }                 
>         ]
> ```

Now I want to update the `isSelected` key if the product exits in MongoDB; I want something like below

> ```
>         var outputJson = [
>             {
>                 'Product' : 'TV',
>                 'isSelected': 0
>             },
>             {
>                 'Product' : 'Radio',
>                 'isSelected': 1
>             },
>             {
>                 'Product' : 'Book',
>                 'isSelected': 0
>             },                      
>             {
>                 'Product' : 'Watch',
>                 'isSelected': 1
>             }                 
>         ]
> ```

Here is the code that I am trying, but I am not getting the above result

```
outputJson.forEach(function(key,value){
 wishlistData.find({userID:req.user.id}, function(err,data{
  data.forEach(function(k,i){
    if (data[i].product=== outputJson[value].Product){
      outputJson[value].isSelected = 1
     }
   })
 }); 
})
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What does `wishlistData` look like? By the way your inner callback function has a missing `)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the callback function to `forEach` is called with the item in the array as the first argument, so `data[i]` and `outputJson[value]` are redundant.

You should make use of mongoose's `findOne` method to see if there's at least one match, and you can pass in `Product` as follows

```
outputJson.forEach(function(item) {
  wishlistData.findOne({userID: req.user.id, product: item.Product}, function(err, data) {
    if (data !== null) { // if it actually found a match
      item.isSelected = 1;
    }
  });
});
```

But keep in mind that mongoDB queries are asynchronous, so `outputJson` would still be the same right after the `forEach` loop. You might want to use promises and `Promise.all` to ensure that you do stuff with outputJson after all the queries have been processed:

```
Promise.all(outputJson.map(function(item) {
  return wishlistData.findOne({userID: req.user.id, product: item.Product}).then(function(err, data) {
    if (data !== null) { // if it actually found a match
      item.isSelected = 1;
    }
  });
})).then(function() {
    // do stuff with outputJson here
});
```

Comment: thank you got your response, this worked, Please see changes that i did  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48677384/2507099)

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
if (data[i].product=== outputJson[value].Product){
      outputJson[value].isSelected = 1
     }
```

by

```
if (data[k].product=== outputJson[key].Product){
      outputJson[key].isSelected = 1
     }
```

each callback function have first argument as index

Comment: Nope, `key` would be the item at each step of iteration (each of the objects)

Comment: @Ambyjkl ok i am confused with jquery $.each and javascript foEach;

Comment: wishlistData.find({userID:req.user.id}, function(err,data{    why don't you close bracket after data like wishlistData.find({userID:req.user.id}, function(err,data){

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Ambyjkl, you guidence worked Promise made the trick, I made minor changes to your script and it started working

```
Promise.all(outputJson.map(function(i,k) {
  return wishlistData.findOne({userID: req.user.id, product: i.Product}).then(function(data, err) {
    if (data !== null) { // if it actually found a match
      i.isSelected = 1;
    }
  });
})).then(function() {
    console.log(outputJson);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, why are you doing the same mongo query repeatedly for each object in the Array, as it will give you the same result. Also use the lodash library 'lodash'. This is how you can achieve this:

```
var _ = require('lodash')
wishlistData.find({userID:req.user.id}, function (err, data) {
    var dataMap = _.indexBy(data, "product");
    outputJson.forEach(function(key,value){
        if(!_.isEmpty(_.get(dataMap, key.Product))) {
            key.isSelected = 1;
        }
    })
}
```